# How to run a function only at the end of the month in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm doing a website and the backend is nodeJS. I need to reset some information in the database every end of the month but I don't know how can I do a function that will be executed the last day of the month at 23:59. Any idea about how can I do that?

Comment: Use a cronjob https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) for that:

```js
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 1 * *', () => {
  console.log('running on the 1st day of the month at 00:00');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change some information of database using moment function in cronjobs.

example:

```
const startOfMonth = moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
const endOfMonth   = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
```